# Как подключить изменения на сайте при изменении в базе данных?

Tags: php, yii2

Как в yii2 или просто при помощи php   систему оповещений как http://ru.stackoverflow.com facebook vk.com и т.д. например кто то написал и без перезагрузки страницы носится изменение на страницу. Уверен что решения есть в интеренете есть но я их не нашел :( помогите ссылками пожалуйста.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/ или setInterval + $.ajax И помните, что PHP - это выполнение со стороны сервера, а не клиента, так что смотрите в сторону javascript

Comment: Используйте Ajax. А так есть PAjax для Yii2. Почитайте: http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-vnikaem-v-pjax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что Вам нужно почти не имеет никакого отношения к PHP.
PHP-процесс на сервере принимает запрос, обрабатывает его и *умирает*. Есть, конечно, **ReactPHP** (http://reactphp.org/), но это чуть для других задач. 
Вам действительно стоит смотреть в чуть другую сторону: *javascript* и *WebSockets* (https://habrahabr.ru/post/79038/).

Либо эмулировать подобное поведение через *AJAX-запросы* с интервалом (*вот, к слову, интересная статья - https://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/, с содержанием ознакомился, прочитав по диагонали - мой вывод такой: Вам почитать будет интересно, но в продакшн, я бы такое решение на запускал*).

Стоит сказать, что если Вы будете использовать *WebSockets*, то все равно стоит продумать про фолбэк сценарии в *ajax*, особенно если ориентируетесь на то, чтобы сделать полноценную версию приложения для мобильных устройств.