# Если в таблицу добавлена запись, то сделать запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Можно как то проверить, если добавлена новая запись в таблицу, то сделать запрос?

То есть **Клиент отправил сообщение** добавляем в базу.

В окне консультанта делаем запрос в базу.Вытаскиваем отправленное **сообщение от клиента**.

Я знаю вариант отправлять запрос в базу каждую секунду через Settimeout, ajax.
Но думаю это создаст много проблем из за много запросов вроде могут заблокировать сайт.

Comment: Блокировка сайта зависит от хостинга. Например, у timeweb тариф сильно зависит от нагрузки на mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать ajax запрос через setInterval, либо использовать веб-сокеты.

Для того, что бы не делать каждый ajax запрос подключение к бд, а тем более запрос, создайте текстовый файл и храните в нем дату последних изменений в бд. PHP скрипт, который будет отвечать на ajax запрос должен перед тем, как подключается к бд, читать дату последнего изменения файла и сравнивать с той, что пришел в ajax запросе (придется на клиентской стороне хранить это число). Если время совпадает, отдаем заголовок Last-Modified и больше ничего, [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) умеет правильно реагировать на такие заголовки (смотрите ifModified). Если время различается, идем в базу.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно давал ответ на вопрос по этой теме: [Как подключить изменения на сайте при изменении в базе данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536054/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/536082#536082)

Если коротко, то *PHP* сам по себе не предназначен для подобных задач.
Танцы с интервалами и *ajax*, на данный момент считаются устаревшими, для Вашей задачи идеально подходят *WebSockets* (https://habrahabr.ru/post/79038/). Тем не менее, зачастую приходится прописывать сценарии, для случаев, когда веб-сокеты по каким-либо (зачастую независящим от Вас) причинам не доступны, и прописывать фолбэк в *ajax*.

@ilyaplot подсказал хороший прием с проверкой на изменения до того, как кидать запрос в базу. В любом случае, интервал стоит ставить реже чем каждую секунду (думаю, что раз в 10-15 секунд будет нормально).

Comment: Я обычно применял предложенный метод в тех случаях, где вебсокеты были как пушка для воробья. Даже 2-3 запроса в секунду показывали нормальный резульат и не давали существенной нагрузки на сервер. Правда, я слал запрос прямо на файл, а в случае isModified слал запрос уже на php скрипт и отключал обработчик на секунду-две.

Comment: Но сегодня, конечно же, самый "модный" вариант - Angular + Websockets

Comment: Я думаю не буду замарачиватся проста поставлю на интервал.Думал есть какойто легкий способ